# Android GridView add FooterView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` and I need to add a footer view to. I know this is possible to be do with a `ListView` using code like this:

```
       LinearLayout layoutFooter = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerview, null);
       final ListView listView = getListView();
       listView.addFooterView(layoutFooter);
```

But how do I do the same with `GridViews`? This approach doesn't seem to be working for `GridView`. Any idea? Cheers.

Comment: you could give RecyclerView a try?

Comment: Could you give me an example for this ?

Comment: [there](https://gist.github.com/hister/d56c00fb5fd2dfaf279b) you are.

Comment: You mean to change the whole gridview to RecyclerView. I do not want that to be honest cause I think RecycleView needs appcombat  v7 library and I am not using that.

Comment: then you have to write your own GridView subclass in order to add support for Header/Footer View.

Comment: Okey cheers that's all i wanted to know, I am just determined now that natively android cannot support header/footer views.

Answer (score 0):

use relative layout as a parent layout and set your footer ,center and header postion and put your grid view in center position and desired footerview at footer position.

Comment: I have tried this but it always displays the button on top of the GridView.

Comment: I should work did you check all the view ? their arrangement . You have to align 3 linear layout in a relative layout and grid layout should be child  of center one then try .

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) a good soluction to do this.

Comment: Yeah I have seen this too, but is it possible to be done without a library ?

Comment: @Kristo1990 yes. it possible